# C , Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers

i have the following code:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
void* Globalptr = NULL;
void func(ptrtype* input)
{
 ((ptrtype*)Globalptr) = input;
}
```

I get Error on line `((ptrtype*)Globalptr) = input;` says " expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Comment: Why do you need a #define for NULL? Type-casting needs to be done for values to fit into the variables.

Comment: `NULL` should be brought in by including `stdlib.h` or one of the other headers that defines it; not writing it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must make the data to match the variable (lvalue), and not change the type of the variable to match the data:

```
Globalptr = (void*)input;
```

But since you can convert any data pointer to `void*` in C, you can simply do:

```
Globalptr = input;
```

Answer (score 3):

When using void pointer, have to type cast like

```
Globalptr = (void *)input;
```

And not like

```
((ptrtype*)Globalptr) = input;
```

Comment: `Globalptr = (ptrtype *)input;` does not make sense in this case since it already is ptrtype*

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you should include header file stdlib.h to bring in NULL and also don't create NULL on your own as you have done.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
void* Globalptr = NULL;
void func(ptrtype* input)
{
  Globalptr = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works whatever the type of the pointer is (inside a function, as yours):

```
Pointer_Type pointer_1 = *((Pointer_Type*) pointer_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have made sense if GlobalPtr was of type "ptrtype *" and input was of type "void *" like below:

```
ptrtype *Globalptr = NULL;
void func(void *input)
{
  Globalptr = (ptrtype *)input;
}
```

In your case what you could do is to convert Globalptr from "void *" to "ptrtype *".
Like others already mentioned, "NULL" should not be used in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that the cast produces an rvalue and the left operand of the assignment operator requires a modifiable lvalue.

That is why the expression ((ptrtype*)Globalptr) is not correct and as others pointed out cast is done on the right hand side of the assignment operator.

please see the [lvalue_rvalue_link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05lvalue.htm) for details.